# Relating a proof to a Haskell program

Tags: proof-techniques, correctness-proof, formal-methods, haskell

I am trying to relate the following [integer square root theorem](http://www.nuprl.org/MathLibrary/integer_sqrt/)

$\forall x: \mathbb{N}, \exists y : \mathbb{N}((y^2 \leq x) \land  (x < (y+1)^2))$

and its proof to its role as a specification of the Integer Square Root `isqrt` ($\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$) function in a Haskell program.

Below is a [inductive proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891932/inductive-proof-using-fitch-software) of the theorem and the related Haskell program. 
The proof was done using natural deduction in the [Fitch system](https://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/distributed/L/bo12734345.html), hence there are notational differences between code and proof e.g. no $\leq$ in Fitch.

For my question the details of the proof are not important. I wish to focus on the base case, and the two cases involving  $\exists$-Elimination and $\lor$-Elimination.

I used Quickcheck as a reasonable check that the theorem holds in the code.

I can see that cases **1** and **2** in the proof correspond to the guard conditions in the Haskell definition of `isqrt` function. I did not specify, prove, and implement  the function `isqrt` in any structured way. I just used any examples I could find. I believe that there must some more formal transformation from proof to code that I am missing. So despite having written both the proof and code the precise correspondence between both eludes my comprehension.

Is there a technical name for this form of proof to program relation?
I would be grateful for an explanation or pointer to the literature.

[image: Inductive Proof]

```
module Peano where
import Test.QuickCheck

data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving Show
-- addition
(+@) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
Z +@ y = y
(S x) +@ y = S (x +@ y)
-- multiplication
(*@) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
x *@ Z = Z 
x *@ S y = (x *@ y) +@ x 
-- square
sqr x = x *@ x 
-- equality
(=@) :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
Z =@ Z  = True
(S m) =@  (S n) = m =@ n 
_=@ _  = False 

-- lesst than
(<@) :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
Z <@ Z = False 
Z <@ x | not(x =@ Z) = True 
x <@ Z | not(x =@ Z) = False 
(S x) <@ (S y) = x <@ y 


-- less than or equal
(<=@) :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
x <=@ y = if (x =@ y) || (x <@ y) then True else False


-- Integer square root function
isqrt Z = Z
isqrt (S x) | (sqr (S (isqrt x))) <=@  (S x) = (S (isqrt x))
            | (S x) <@ (sqr (S (isqrt x))) = isqrt x

-- test with Quickcheck
instance Arbitrary Nat where
 arbitrary = oneof [return Z, (S  <$>  arbitrary) ]

isqrtPostCondition :: Nat  -> Bool
isqrtPostCondition x  = (sqr (isqrt x) <=@ x) && (x <@ sqr(S (isqrt x)))
check = quickCheck isqrtPostCondition
-- +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your goal is to “prove”  --I'm using bullets “•” for syntactic separators--
$$ ∀x \;•\;\; ∃y \;•\;\; y² ≤ x < (y+1)²$$

---

#### Proof Methods

In the natural deduction style, one proves “∀ x : ℕ • P x” by proving
two statements:

```
Base case      :: P 0
Inductive step :: P a ⇒ P (S a) , for a : ℕ and S successor function
```

Where, in this case,
$$P x \;\;≡\;\; ∃y \;•\; y² ≤ x < (y+1)²$$

In the constructive fashion, one proves “∃ y • Q x” by 
*actually finding* such a $y$ using whatever data is available.

#### Base case

For the [base] case the input `x` is `0`, and we need to *find*
some $y$ with $y² ≤ x < (y+1)²$. Clearly $y = 0$ works as shown
in the proof your posted.

#### Inductive step

For the [inductive] case where the input `x` is of the shape `S a`,
we need to *find* a $y$ with $y² ≤ S a < (y+1)²$, (*).

1. However, we have the assumption $P a$ which gives us a $b$ with
   $b² ≤ a < (b+1)²$ --which looks really close to the goal (*).
2. To reach our goal (*), let's do the simplest thing possible:
   replace $a$ with $S a$ in (1) thereby obtaining
   $b² ≤ S a < (b + 1)²$. Because of (1), and the transitivity of ≤,
   the left part is true and the whole thing reduces to:
   $$S a < (b + 1)²$$
3. So if this is true, then we are done and the answer is $b$.
4. If it is not true, then we must have it complement:
   $$(b + 1)² ≤ S a$$

   - But from (1) we also have $a < (b + 1)² = b² + 2b + 1$
     thus we obtain $S a = a + 1 < (b² + 2b + 1) + 1 ≤ b² + 4b + 2 = ((b + 1) + 1)²$
   - Hence, we have found that $(b + 1)² ≤ S a < ((b + 1) + 1)²$
     and so we may take the output $y$ to be $b + 1$ for our goal (*).

---

## Curry-Howard: Proving ≅ Programming

The above was a proof [sketch] which corresponds to the a program.

A proof of $$∀ x : ℕ • ∃ y : ℕ • R(x, y)$$
corresponds to the program

```
-- Output y = prog x satisfies relationship R(x, y), for all input x.
prog :: Int → Int
prog 0  = “the y found in the base case of the proof”
prog n  = “the y found in the inductive step, 
             along with any conditionals and recursive calls”
```

Applying this to our above proof yields,

```
prog :: Int → Int
prog 0 = 0
prog n = let a = n - 1 ; b = prog a
         in
           if   a + 1 <= (b + 1) * (b + 1)
           then b
           else b + 1
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for your clear and very helpful answer.  You provide a proof in a "constructive fashion".  Is my Fitch proof non-constructive?

Comment: Your proof is also constructive; mine is less formal but is more explicit about what the constructions are.